# How to stop apache2 when `apachectl stop` doesn't stop it?

Tags: apache2, macports, osx-elcapitan

I am using OSX El Capitan. This comes with the default apache where I find stuff at `private/etc/apache2`. I also had apache2 installed via macports which was stored in `opt/local/apache2`.

When I

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

and go to `localhost` it still displays that "It works!". This document is found in `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html`.

My first thought was to remove apache2 from `opt` using

```
sudo port uninstall apache2
```

This hasn't appeared to have removed anything.

Which apache am I running? How can I stop it? Ideally, I would like to return my apache-ness to the default of El Capitan: what needs to be done to achieve that?

Comment: Not answering your question. But have you tried Xampp => https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html ??

Comment: @kkaosninja Yes. And I fear it was the cause of my problems (my original problem that has now been superseded by this one), so I unistalled it.

Comment: `netstat -plt` should give you a list of processes. Find the name of the one on port 80. Next, use `ps` to find out whether that's MacPorts' or a different one. Btw, if you used launchd to start this server, just stopping it will likely only trigger launchd to restart it. If it's MacPorts', try `sudo port unload apache2`.

Comment: @neverpanic I just tried `netstat` and it tells me that it is unknown protocol. I did `ps -ax|grep apache2` and got `/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start`. So I assume this means the macports apache2 is running. I then did `sudo port unload apache2`  and got `Error: Processing of port apache2 failed`.

Comment: When it fails it should print the path of a main.log file. What are its contents?